# what precautions to be kept in mind while naming session variables

Tags: php, security, session, session-variables

If the session variables are named the same in different domains , it may cause some security issues as the pages of new URL may grant access to its pages without signing in if a previous domain has initialized sessions with the same names as of the 2nd one.. How can we keep names different and secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would not cause a security issue. SESSIONS from different domains can not interfere with each other. For example if you log in to www.x.com and they set a $_SESSION[ 'id' ], then if you go onto www.y.com, even if they check for a $_SESSION[ 'id' ] to check if a user is logged in it would not pick up the session from www.x.com because it is on a different domain.

If this would be possible it would cause huge security issues with every website.

Comment: I got ur point , and thats right, but i have noted that this problem exists if i m running it on localhost..

Comment: Yeh this would happen on your localhost. To get around it you could have two arrays inside your session. One to hold information related to website x and the other for website y.